# Scraping a web page and extracting words that begin with a particular symbol

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, wget

I would like to extract all the just the twitter handles from the following: http://twitaholic.com/top100/followers/

All the twitter handles start with an `@`

So something like `wget twitaholic.com/top100/followers/ | grep -oh "@"` to print just the the handles, but that doesn't work (only prints the `@`). What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `-o` option of `grep` and only specifying one character, that is `@`, also you don't need the `-h` option.

**Try this:**

```
wget twitaholic.com/top100/followers/ | grep -o "@[^<]*"
```

What we are telling `grep` here is look for `@` symbol and capture everything until you see a `<` symbol. This is because the line that carries the handle looks like this:

```
;@BarackObama<br
```

So you effectively need to extract text starting from `@` to `<`.

**Output:**

```
$ wget twitaholic.com/top100/followers/ | grep -o "@[^<]*" | head -10
@katyperry
@justinbieber
@BarackObama
@ladygaga
@YouTube
@taylorswift13
@britneyspears
@rihanna
@jtimberlake
@instagram
```